# Bootstrap 3 - 940px width grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 on a new project. The layout is to be a 940px max width (desktop etc), 12 col (60px column, 20px gutter).

I've set `.container` to a `max-width: 940px;` but this makes the grid off, for some reason. This gives me 50px column with 30px gutter. So i need to cut down the gutter to 20px and add the 10px to the column.

But how do i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 970px;
  }
```

Note: 970 minus 30px (gutter) makes 940px for your design.

**update**

See: http://bootply.com/86257

Set @grid-gutter-width to 20px; and recompile bootstrap.

In this case your .container /.row will have a width of 960px. Defined in variabless.less:
`@container-desktop:            ((940px + @grid-gutter-width));`

Note if setting `@container-large-desktop: @container-desktop` in variables.less i don't need the media query above.

Comment: Yes, but this still makes the columns and gutter the wrong width? The design specs i got says a picture in 4 columns is 300px wide - this would not happen with the current setup?

Comment: could you add a screen of your design? See also http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid the medium grid (970) has a max column width of ((970 - gutter /12)) 78px. 4 x 78 makes 312. including gutter. You could make your image fir by adding the class `img-responsive` maybe.

Comment: I added a picture of the grid above. 940px width. 60px columns with 20px gutter. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use the original LESS version of bootstrap (get it from github).

Open variables.less and look for // Media queries breakpoints

```
// Large screen / wide desktop
@screen-lg:                  1200px; // change this
@screen-lg-desktop:          @screen-lg;
```

Change the last breakpoint to 9999px for example, and this will prevent this breakpoint to be reached, so your site always load the previous media query:

```
@screen-md:                  992px; // this one has 940px container
@screen-desktop:             @screen-md;
```

To change the column width and gutter, scroll a little bit down in the same file and look for

```
// Grid system
// --------------------------------------------------

// Number of columns in the grid system
@grid-columns:              12;
// Padding, to be divided by two and applied to the left and right of all columns
@grid-gutter-width:         30px;
// Point at which the navbar stops collapsing
@grid-float-breakpoint:     @screen-tablet;
```

Here you can configure it

And finally, ofcource compile bootstrap.less file in css.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You must comment the following section in bootstrap.responsive.css for start 940 view

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}
```

Comment: Not sure i understand this reply?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 don't have a  bootstrap.responsive.css file.